# How to set log direction in Spring Cloud DataFlow

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I have set

```
spring.cloud.deployer.local.workingDirectoriesRoot=D:\\Deploy
```

in application.properties to define log folder.

However, It does not works, the log of task when I launched is written on java.io.tmpdir (C:/..../temp/).

I am using spring-cloud-dataflow-server-core version 2.3.0.RELEASE
Does I need to put these config in dataflow-server.yml ?
How can I configure the log folder of SCDF and their tasks?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59244299/how-to-set-log-direction-in-spring-cloud-dataflow.

Comment: I posted the wrong link. Here's the duplicate from the backlog: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/3686.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just added some tests for windows and noticed that correct format (assuming task name is timestamp) which actually works on windows when using drive letter is:

```
deployer.timestamp.local.working-directories-root=file:/C:/tmp
```

Think is how in a spring world binding works from `String` to `java.nio.file.Path`. For those interested to know more, It's spring core's `PathEditor` which uses `Paths.get(URI)`, thus need for `file:`.

Comment: Your is correct but this work for me: spring.cloud.dataflow.task.platform.local.accounts.default.working-directories-root = D:\\Deploy\\logs

Answer (score 1):

The property `workingDirectoriesRoot` is a `local` deployer property and not an application property. Hence, it needs to be passed when launching the task.

```
task launch <task-name> --properties "deployer.<task-name>.local.workingDirectoriesRoot=D:\\Deploy"
```